# How do I return the newly created ID after an insert statement from an inline SQL statement in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertOrUpdateDirector(Director director)
{
    int idReturned = 0;

    string query = null;
    myConnection.Open();
    if (director.Operation == 'I')
    {
      query = "INSERT...";
    }
    else if (director.Operation == 'U')
    {
      query = "UPDATE ...";
    }
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();

    idReturned = "???";

    return idReturned;
}
```

I'm simply trying to return the newly created ID after the insert statement. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to your query `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the insert.
and call

```
idReturned = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

instead of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Then check to see if idReturned is null, cmd.ExecuteScalar() will return null for your update query, the primary key should be party of the Director object so you can do:

```
if(idReturned == null){
    return director.DirectorId //just guessing at name of id property here for example sake
}else{
    return idReturned;
}
```

You should already have the primary key passed into InsertOrUpdateDirector to write the update query.

Comment: No only works with INSERT. If you are using primary key to update record don't you already have the primary key? I am editing my answer as I mistakenly added update when I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this code,I hope this will work
myConnection.Open();
    if (director.Operation == 'I')
        {
          query = "INSERT...";
    string query1="select  createdId  from table";

        }
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    Sqlcommand cmd1=new SqlCommand(query1,myConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int CreatedId=cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    return  CreatedId;
        myConnection.Close();
     myConnection.Close();
```